# Big-O complexity for a function tips

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm a student and I really can't fully understand how to calculate big-O's for complicated functions, I tried doing the exercices provided by the teacher and by the book we use (Discrete mathematics) and I still feel I don't really understand how it works when it comes to complicated functions, knowing that I'm really good at other areas in mathematics, however, my question is, do you have a source, video, maybe a book you recommend that explains how big-O works?

Comment: 'Complex' functions... I hope you don't mean $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Kaind not at all, by complex I mean for example $f_5(n)=log_3(n^3)+log_2(n^n)$

Comment: Yeah, maybe don't use the word 'complex'; use say 'complicated' functions. Btw a hint is if you know the Taylor series polynomials, you can find O quite quickly.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf) excellent article by Hildebrand. There's also a great resource in chapter 9 of Concrete Mathematics. If you want a very detailed treatment of asymptotics (where you can see big Oh used in context) you might try De Bruijns "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis"